# Liquibase Deployment - SQL Alchemy psycopg2 plugin error

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, liquibase

We have a shell script that runs a liquibase deployment. This deployment script has been running with no issues for years on our ubuntu box.

We have migrated over to Windows running through a powershell terminal in VSCode. The script starts to run in a "GIT for windows" window and after printing the initial message to the GIT window it fails with the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:psycopg2

I do have psycopg2 as one of my libraries installed in my powershell environment. After some initial research I checked and we are using the  postgresql:// scheme instead of just postgres://.

Any ideas as to why I am still getting this error? Nothing has changed in the script/process except moving to VS Code in Windows as opposed to VS Code in Ubuntu.

Its probably something dumb I'm missing. Thanks!

I have checked the scheme we're using based on initial google searches.

I also verified all libraries in my windows environment match what we have in the ubuntu environment, including psycopg2.